# dotnet ef migration list not finding migrations in Migration folder

Tags: .net, f#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I was following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite) (On linux and converted to F#) 
Migrations were created successfully (3 files in the `Migrations` directory.) But `dotnet ef database update` says everything is up to date and `dotnet ef migrations list` says no migrations found. When I check the created sqlite file manually it contains only an empty __EFMigrationsHistory table.

The `context.Database.Migrate()` and `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` methods also don't pick up any migrations.

I'm thinking maybe my fsproject is missing reference to the Migrations folder but I'm not sure what a reference to that would look like.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to get migrations working.

1. I had to *also* convert the generated migration files to F#.
   [This blog post](https://medium.com/real-world-fsharp/using-f-with-net-core-aa6cfc9ef547) by Ody Mbegbu was very helpful here. (Although some modifications have to be made to account for changes since v1.)
2. I had to add the newly converted .fs migration files to the fsproj.